# How to find how far away could a binary system be?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, astronomy

Human eye resolution is about one arcminute. Two stars in a binary system are separated
by 10 AU. How far away can they be such that your eye could still distinguish them as two separate stars rather than a single star? The Hubble Space Telescope (HST) has a diameter of about 2.4 m. If the HST measured the stars in the visible wavelength bands. Could someone please explain how far away could the binary system be before HST could not resolve the system into two separate stars rather than one light source?

Comment: If the binary stars are of 2 spectral types, then the HST will always be able to tell there are 2 stars (even only using visible light), no matter how far away they are.

Answer (score 2):

For the eye, draw a picture.  You have an isosceles triangle with the small angle one arc minute and base 10 AU.  What is the altitude?  Bisect the small angle and you have two right triangles.  For the second, you need to compute the small angle of the same triangle from the diffraction limit on a diameter of 2.4 meters.  Can you find that equation in your book?